# convert null value to string "null"

Tags: php, postgresql

I have an input field that accepts strings in a form. After submitting the form, it is then saved to the database and attached the inputted string back in the field. Here's the scenario:

Tester breaks my code by inputting: `<hello world>`
The output is: `&lt;hello world&gt;`
The desired output should be: `<hello world>`

I managed to fix this by using `htmlspecialchars_decode($form_data['val']);`

Now, what the tester did this time is he input: `null`
The output is : blank (empty string)

My solution is:

```
    // not so efficient since he can always break my code by inputting: "NULL"
    if($form_data['val'] === null) {
        //problem here is when he input: "NULL"
        $form_data['val'] = "null";
    }
```

I want to have an output based on what the user inputs. The only problem here is the NULL or null value inputted. zzzz

Comment: How your are saving values into database? what is the data type of database field? Is null value allowed in your database field?

Comment: in my practice, I wouldnt sanitize user input but only validate them, and save in the database as original as  possible. then whenever a content involves user input, just `htmlspecialchar` them all

Answer (score 0):

```
if($form_data['val'] === 'null' or $form_data['val'] === '') {
        $form_data['val'] = "null";
    }
```

Comment: The problem here is when user input is "NULL".

Comment: Put this condition => if($form_data['val'] === 'NULL')

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
$form_data['val'] = (is_null($form_data['val']) || empty($form_data['val'])) ? 'null' : $form_data['val'];
```

Comment: The data is $form_data['val'] = string 'null'  when submitted.

I looked at the database and turns out that the actual value saved is NULL (empty) so when I pull it back to the form, it has a value of '' (empty)

Comment: Configure db to not to allow null values

Comment: and instead of === use == in checking for null values

Comment: @ZSMJ in your db table config you have allowed null value for that column so that value is inserted NULL when php code value is blank.